Can 'Negativity vs Positivity' be a Biblical hermeneutic?
I asked on our sister site Christianity about whether "Negative Prophecy" was an actual Christian teaching. This has hermeneutical implications in addition to theological because prophecy might exist both inside the Bible and outside. My question here is about using "negativity vs positivity" as any means of understanding or interpreting Bible passages.
Is "positive-negative" a lens the Bible uses?
If something is to be applied as a hermeneutic, then the writers needed to think that way on some level, unless we are using something like a Notarikon hermeneutic. Using negative-positive is no different.
The concept of Negavite vs Positive thinking originates with Napoleon Hill's Positive Mental Attitude (PMA) from 1937. In 1960, Stone indicates agreement, who:

defines positive mental attitude as comprising the 'plus' characteristics represented by words as faith, integrity, hope, optimism, courage, initiative, generosity, tolerance, tact, kindliness and good common sense.1

From Selling Power:

In 1960 Stone and Hill collaborated on the bestseller, Success Through a Positive Mental Attitude (Prentice-Hall) which was translated into German, French, Portuguese and Japanese.

Examples
From Christians TT: Prayer Against Negativity

With authority, I rebuke his negativity out, standing firm in Jesus’ mighty name! Lovingly envelop me, Lord, under the protective and redeeming blood of the Lamb. Infiltrate my mind, my body, and my soul, ensuring that no darkness finds a foothold.
Guard and guide me with Your supreme divinity, so that any negative thoughts that arise are promptly met with and deterred by my unwavering, unbreakable faith in You.
Philippians 4:8 ...

The writer quotes a Bible passage in light of "rebuking negativity", basically arguing that Phil 4:8 can be understood through this positive-negative thinking paradigm.

Ref: Phil 4 (NASB)

From Quora:

Do the positive passages in the Bible really outweigh the negative ones?

...How does one define a "negative" or "positive" Bible passage? This seems to indicate that the definition is left up to Napoleon Hill.
From Talk Jesus: A negative report affects ALL!! (Numbers 13:1-15:41)

The result was that panic and discouragement spread throughout the camp, and it wasn’t just a few thousand Israelites, but rather a few million, discouraged by 10 negative leaders. And 10 out-vote 2! Even though Kaleb and Yehoshua tried to encourage the people, the negatives won over. ...
The reason for "spying out" the land was for observation! making invasion plans, to take notes, just like scouts of the Armed Forces do today when preparing for battle. But, when the spies said "however" or in some translations "but" those words inject negativity. From HOPE to DISPAIR and it affected the whole camp of a million and more Israelites. So, Bad news for these negative speakers, death for them, and a "waiting game" for the rest.
Another thing to mention is that just before this event, we remember that Miriam spoke against her brother Moses, saying that "Hey, hasn't Adonai spoken through us all, and not only through Moshe?' and the result of her "Leshon Hara" was that Adonai struck her with "Tzara-at" and had to stay outside the camp for 7 days. Ten of the twelve spies spoke "Leshon Hara" against the Land of Israel! and as a result, Adonai struck them all down with a plague!

...Leshon Hara remains undefined in that article, but seems implied to mean "speaking negative" in the blog's context. And, the article never addresses the matter of disobeying God or believing that God was either unwilling or incapable of protecting them. It seems the blogger here would have us think that the reason for God sending Israel to wander 40 years was because they lacked Napoleon Hill's Positive Mental Attitude.

Ref: Num 13 (NASB)

What is PMA when applied to Bible interpretation?
Indeed, there are positives and negatives in Phil 4:8, but is "positive-negative" sufficiently do justice to reflect what Paul sees in Phil 4:8?
Indeed, the 10 bad spies of Numbers 13 were being rather "negative". But, does "lack of PMA" fully explain God's reasoning in sentencing them to wander 40 years?
If we use Hillian "Positive Mental Attitude" in understanding Bible texts...

Is it a hermeneutic that reflects what Bible authors were thinking?

Why, and what are some examples to support this in light of the extrabiblical origin?


If not, then, please clarify a few things in an answer...

What are we doing by using PMA as a hermeneutic?

eg We are selectively exploiting Bible segments for a proof-text to support PMA.


What lens did the Bible authors have instead? (Across both Phil 4 and Num 13 and others)

eg bless vs curse, praise God or self, etc


What is PMA to Bible hermeneutics?

eg It is eisegesis. It imposes humanist philosophy.


What are some dangers of using PMA as a hermeneutic if it should not be used that way?

eg We might dismiss wisdom teaching about self-control. We might use it to replace Substitutionary Atonement in theology.


Does "positive-negative" have a place to belong on the application side of Bible study, just not on the hermeneutical-exegesis-interpretation side?

eg Some Bible passages support "focusing thoughts on virtuous things. The Bible expands beyond PMA to include "respect" as a virtue.






1. Hill, Napoleon; Stone, W. Clement Stone; preface by Og Mandino; with a new introduction by W. Clement (1987). Success through a positive mental attitude. New York: Pocket Books. ISBN 0671743228.

A suggestion for future submissions. Focus on one question per post to allow for greater comprehension of the question and to enable more focused answers.
Starting with definitions so we are all on the same page.
Hermeneutic

is the theory and methodology of interpretation

The definition of hermeneutic can depend on how it's used.
Again from the wiki article

Hermeneutics was initially applied to the interpretation, or exegesis, of scripture, and has been later broadened to questions of general interpretation. The terms hermeneutics and exegesis are sometimes used interchangeably. Hermeneutics is a wider discipline which includes written, verbal, and nonverbal

I'll be using "hermeneutic" in the broader sense - the theory and methodology of interpretation.
Eisegesis

is the process of interpreting text in such a way as to introduce one's own presuppositions, agendas or biases. It is commonly referred to as reading into the text. It is often done to "prove" a pre-held point of concern, and to provide confirmation bias corresponding with the pre-held interpretation and any agendas supported by it.

Exegesis

A critical explanation of a text.

Exegesis focuses primarily upon the word and grammar of texts.
From Wiki

One who practices exegesis is called an exegete (/ˌɛksɪˈdʒiːt/; from Greek ἐξηγητής), the plural of exegesis is exegeses (/ˌɛksɪˈdʒiːsiːz/), and adjectives are exegetic or exegetical (e.g., exegetical commentaries). In biblical exegesis, the opposite of exegesis (to draw out) is eisegesis (to draw in), in the sense of an eisegetic commentator "importing" or "drawing in" their own subjective interpretations into the text, unsupported by the text itself. Eisegesis is often used as a derogatory term.

From britanica.com

The sacred status of the Bible in Judaism and Christianity rests upon the conviction that it is a receptacle of divine revelation. This understanding of the Bible as the word of God, however, has not generated one uniform hermeneutical principle for its interpretation.

britanica.com goes on to discuss four major types of hermeneutics

literal
moral
allegorical
anagogical.

Any system of understanding scripture can be given a set of rules and a name and appear on this list.
A hermeneutic system can focus on exegesis, eisegesis or some blend of the two.
You question asks:


If we use Hillian "Positive Mental Attitude" in understanding Bible texts, what is that?

Is it a hermeneutic that reflects what Bible authors were thinking?



If not, then:
3. What lens did the Bible authors have instead? (Across both Phil 4 and Num 13 and others)
4. What is PMA to Bible hermeneutics? Is it eisegesis? Is it imposed humanist philosophy?
5. What are some dangers of using PMA as a hermeneutic if it should not be used that way?
6. Does "positive-negative" have a place to belong on the application side of Bible study, just not on the hermeneutical-exegesis-interpretation side?


Responding to the questions by number.

If we use "Positive Mental Attitude" in understanding Bible texts then we are using those principles as a hermeneutic - yet another method of interpretation then we have another set of rules to use to interpret the Bible along with literal, moral, allegorical, anagogical etc.

In order to have a hermeneutic that reflects what the Bible authors were thinking we would need to use a set of rules for understanding scripture that focus on authorial intent. The most generous understanding of a "Positive Mental Attitude" hermeneutic would require the reader to interpret the Bible according to a reader definition of "positive" and "negative" and understand the author's writing in light of the reader's perspective.
There might be some sort of blending of a literal or grammatic/historic hermeneutic (a hermeneutic that focuses on authors intent) along with the human definition of "positive" and "negative" but the outcome would be to move away from author's intent as the sole goal of understanding.

The Bible authors are the source and we are the readers. When the authors of the Bible interpret other scripture we can seek to understand how they interpreted scripture - if we use a hermeneutic that cares about authorial intent. When the authors of the Bible are writing the words they were inspired to write - not quoting anything else - then it's not that the authors have a lens - a particular hermeneutic. The authors of the Bible do have a perspective and that comes out in what they wrote. We can discover the Bible author's perspective if we use a hermeneutic that seeks to draw out the meaning of the text - if we care about what the author meant.

If PMA is used to interpret the Bible then it is yet another hermeneutic. I'm not an expert on PMA. My cursory reading of the links in the question show PMA as a sort of positive thinking philosophy applied to Bible reading. If my understanding is correct it would be solidly eisegesis.

"Danger" is a subjective term. You can create a list of tradeoffs for any hermeneutic system. I am highly biased toward the grammatic/historical hermeneutic that focuses on the idea that "A text cannot mean what it could never have meant for its original readers/hearers" This is the definition of exegesis - to draw out the meaning. Anything other than drawing out the author's intent is either eisegesis or some blend of the exegesis and eisegesis.

I'm not sure what is meant by "the application side of Bible study, just not on the hermeneutical-exegesis-interpretation side". Application is driven by the interpretation. I'm not sure how the two can be separated.


To offer a simple test for exegesis and eisegesis.
It's a question of authority.
Is the text in authority over me - am I to do what the text says? If so, then I am to understand the author's intent and act accordingly.
or
Am I in authority over the text - I can make the text mean what I want and then act accordingly.

I clarified those six points you mentioned to include some examples.

This answer is thorough, but  I feel it only scratches the surface of what you really think. If my understanding is correct it would be solidly eisegesis. I hoped you would start point 4 with that, then continue instead of stopping there.  Much of this answer feels the same, like you are just getting started, and I was more interested in what you would say if you continued.
